# LINQ to SQL, DBML file, data annotations and DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I'm using a DBML file to create a schema for an existing database and I'm also adding new classes into it. Using an overriden `Context` class I've made it so the new tables are created in the database as needed. The new context class works admirably.

However, I'm having a bit of trouble displaying it in a readable way to the user. I've only got Windows Forms at my disposal, so I'm using a `DataGridView` control.

I can create columns manually, sure. But I was hoping I could use data annotations in the model to make use of the automatic column generation capabilities.

I've added annotations to the DBML using a "buddy class", as presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281464/adding-dataannotations-to-auto-generated-dbml-class-mvc-2-0-asp-net).

However, I seem to be missing something, as the DGV class generated default columns for all my fields, despite the fact that, in the data annotations, I've changed the display names of some, ordering and even prevented some fields from being auto-generated at all. Or so I thought, at least.

Any idea what I could be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make code the uses Reflection to get the public properties. From there on use your annotations to select the properties that need to become columns.

Comment: So, automatic use of data annotations with WinForm controls such as DGV is not an option? Reflection is a last resort for me.